# input number верх / вниз

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии верх сумма умножалась, а при нажатии вниз делилась?

```js
$("#kol").change(function() {
    p = $(this).parent().parent();
    kol = $("#kol").val();
    sum = $("#sum").val();
    mul = parseInt(sum * 2);
    res = p.find("#sum");
    res.html(mul);
    total = 0;
    $("span").text(mul);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

Количевство: <input type="number" id="kol" min="1" value="1" step="1"><br><br>

Сумма: <input type="number" id="sum" min="1" value="100" step="1">руб<br><br>
Общая сумма:<span></span>руб
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не понятно задан вопрос и небрежно написан код.
Из вопроса я понял, что нужно при стрелке вверх умножать, а при стрелке вниз делить

```js
$("#kol").change(function() {
  var nV = $(this).val();
  var oV = this.name;
  this.name = nV;
  
  var p=$(this).parent().parent();
  var kol = $("#kol").val();
  var sum = $("#sum").val();
  
  if(nV > oV) {
    mul = parseInt(sum * 2);
    console.log('up');
  } else {
    mul = parseInt(sum / 2);
    console.log('down');
  }
  
  var res=p.find("#sum");
  res.html(mul);
  var total=0;
  $("span").text(mul);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
Количевство:<input type="number" id="kol" min="1" value="1" step="1" name='-1'><br><br>

Сумма:
<input type="number" id="sum" min="1" value="100" step="1" />
руб<br><br>
Общая сумма:<span></span>руб
```

Comment: Спасибо.Вы ответили как я хотел.